# Как запретить смену ориентации при блокировке экрана

Tags: android, orientation

Есть приложение, которое должно показываться только в landscape. В манифесте прописано для activity:

```
android:screenOrientation="landscape"
android:configChanges="orientation"
```

но при блокировке и разблокировке устройства происходит смена ориентации на portrait и landscape соответственно. Естественно при этом пересоздается activity

Как это победить?

Answer (score 0):

Перемести `android:configChanges="orientation"` в `<activity>`